# Exclude few selected fields on group by

Tags: sql

I had a query that was returning member transaction information. This query has an aggregate function to calculate the amount. All is working fine according to its grouping. Now what I need to do is to add two more columns from different tables. I did try to add them unfortunately they are giving me duplicated information with tons number of records.

Can anyone help me I just want to be able to include the two fields on the query and not include them in the group by clause. And also ensure that data returned is not a duplicate

See below is the query I used.

```
DECLARE @LastMonthExtractID Int = 11

SELECT  x.*
    ,lstmnth.Submission ---added 
    ,lm_subt.SubmissionTypeDescription ---added 
FROM    (
SELECT MemberRef --unique key
 , SiteName
 , ChargePeriod
 , SUM(Amount) AS Amount
 , TransactionMap
 , PackageCode

FROM (
  SELECT MemberRef
        , SiteName
        , ChargePeriod
        , Amount
        , PackageCode
        , CASE  WHEN map.TransactionMap = 'JoinFee' AND lstmnth.ChargeDate <> lstmnth.JoinDate THEN 'PayPlan' 
                WHEN map.TransactionMap = 'MemberFee' AND lstmnth.PackageCode LIKE 'PV%' AND lstmnth.SiteID <> 15 THEN 'VitalityMF'  -- must use Package and not CURRENT PACKAGE
                WHEN map.TransactionMap = 'MemberFee' AND lstmnth.PackageCode LIKE 'PV%' AND lstmnth.SiteID = 15  THEN 'PlatVitalityMF' -- PLATINUM
                WHEN map.TransactionMap = 'MemberFee' AND lstmnth.PackageCode LIKE 'Z%' THEN 'ZContract'
                WHEN map.TransactionMap IS NULL THEN 'Other'
                ELSE map.TransactionMap END AS TransactionMap
        --, lstmnth.Submission
        --, lm_subt.SubmissionTypeDescription --added

FROM  dbo.CCX_Billing lstmnth 
LEFT JOIN  dbo.TransactionMap map on lstmnth.TransactionType = map.TransactionType 
                                                AND         lstmnth.TransactionDescription = map.TransactionDescription
                                                AND ISNULL    (lstmnth.AnalysisCode, '') = map.AnalysisCode

 WHERE   lstmnth.ExtractID = @LastMonthExtractID

  ) l
GROUP BY  SiteName, MemberRef, ChargePeriod, PackageCode, TransactionMap
) x
INNER JOIN dbo.CCX_Billing lstmnth ON lstmnth.MemberRef = x.MemberRef
LEFT JOIN  dbo.CCX_Billing_PSubmission lm_sub on lstmnth.SubmissionID = lm_sub.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.CCX_Billing_SubmissionType lm_subt on lm_sub.SubmissionTypeID =     lm_subt.SubmissionID     --added
```

Comment: Problem is that you are using `LEFT JOINS` change all to `INNER` and you will get on row per `GROUP BY` question now is this what you want?

Comment: you mean the outside query or the inner one??

Comment: I mean this `LEFT JOIN  dbo.CCX_Billing_PSubmission lm_sub on lstmnth.SubmissionID = lm_sub.ID` you have more than one relationship to `MemberRef ` so there is no way to get less data.

Comment: so how do I then ensure that I get a join that will help me eliminate the amount of data???